# Cannot find module "collections/deque"

Tags: javascript, deque

Trying to use Deque data structure to answer a programming problem to find all sub arrays with a product less than the target.

As mentioned, I want to use a Deque Data structure. I looked at the usage and think I'm doing it right but by using

```
const Deque = require("collections/deque");
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot find module "collections/deque"
```

If anybody can see what I'm missing please let me know.

This is the code.

```
const Deque = require("collections/deque");

function find_subarrays(arr, target) {
  let result = [],
    product = 1,
    left = 0;
  for (right = 0; right < arr.length; right++) {
    product *= arr[right];
    while (product >= target && left < arr.length) {
      product /= arr[left];
      left += 1;
    }
    const tempList = new Deque();
    for (let i = right; i > left - 1; i--) {
      tempList.unshift(arr[i]);
      result.push(tempList.toArray());
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is collections.js does not come with vanilla JS you have to install it using npm

```
npm install --save collections
```

Or just use built in array method to simulate deque operations.

Comment: what is complexity of the deque?  where is the github project for this?